# How to print another statement in a recursive method when called again

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, methods, stdout

The `addTeam` method asks user for a String input. The new team is added in the arraylist if it does not exists else runs the method again.

I want to change it so that if team already exists in the list it will print "*team already exists! Please enter a new name*" and ask user for input again without printing that first print statement in the method.

edit: I cannot create a new field outside the method. Additionally, it doesn't have to a recursive method necessarily. Using loops may make it work too?

```java
public void addTeam(){
        System.out.print("Please enter the name of the team: ");
        String teamName = In.nextLine();   //In.nextLine() prompts user for String input
        if (teamExists(teamName) == null){ //teamExists() returns the team object if found else null 
            teams.add(new Team(teamName));
            System.out.println("Team " + teamName + " added! ");
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("Team " + teamName + " already exist! ");
            addTeam();
        }
        teamsPage();
    }
```

Sample I/O

```
Please enter the name of the team: Knicks
Team Knicks already exist! Please enter a new name: Lakers
Team Lakers already exist! Please enter a new name: Bulls
Team Bulls already exist! Please enter a new name: Warriors
Team Warriors added!
```

Comment: Do you need to use recursion? Have you considered a loop alternative?

Comment: you are right, i should use while loop, it's much simpler and easy. What should i use as a condition for the while loop?

Comment: Up to you. I might use `while ( ! teamAddedSuccess) `

Answer (score 2):

You have to maintain some kind of `state` that can have two values based on our goal `show first print statement` and `don't show first print statement` we can use `boolean` for that.

So In your case, if we maintain `isAlreadyExist` as a `boolean` we can start to get this behavior with `recursion` and `state management`.

Something like below

```java
public boolean isAlreadyExist = false;

public void addTeam(){
if(!isAlreadyExist) {
        System.out.print("Please enter the name of the team: ");
}
        String teamName = In.nextLine();
        if (teamExists(teamName) == null){ //teamExists() returns the team object if found else null 
            teams.add(new Team(teamName));
            System.out.println("Team " + teamName + " added! ");
            this.isAlreadyExist = false;
        }
        else{
            System.out.print("Team " + teamName + " already exist! ");
            this.isAlreadyExist = true;
            addTeam();
        }
        teamsPage();
    }
```

You can maintain this state in a function argument as well, in this case, you have to pass a new state when you call the function it would increase the memory in the stack for every call but if you maintain the state as the class variable itself or globally in other languages it would be memory efficient maybe.

Comment: Is there a another way? I cannot create a new variable outside the method.

Comment: Yes, you can maintain `state` by passing the argument as I said `addTeam(true)` or `addTeam(false)` based on if you want to print the message or not, but you have to give one parameter.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention, but the method doesn't have to recursive. turns out it will be much simpler with a while loop.

There is nothing to pass to the method when called the first time, but let me try finding a work around

Answer (score 1):

The method didn't had to be recursive. I implemented function using while loops as suggested by a comment.

```java
public void addTeam (){
        System.out.print("Please enter the name of the team: ");
        String teamName = In.nextLine();
        while (teamExists(teamName) != null){
            System.out.print("Team " + teamName + " already exist! Please enter a new name: ");
            teamName = In.nextLine();
        }
        teams.add(new Team(teamName));
        System.out.println("Team " + teamName + " added!");
        teamsPage();
    }
```

I love while loops.